# How to decode \xD6 to ö with asp classic?

Tags: asp-classic

I get a JSON string that contains the swedish character ö and I put it in the variable "`adress`", and when I just do `response.write adress` on the page it is displaying correctly the "`ö`", but when I try to insert it into my mysql db I get this error.

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers fel '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.7.21-log]Incorrect string value: '\xD6STERS...' for column 'postadress' at row 1
```

I have set up the db so it can handle 4 characters and I can insert an emoji and that has 4 characters. The column "adress" is utf8mb4_swedish_ci

And on my server I have set this so that everything should be utf8mb4.
I have this in my mysql configuration file, my.ini

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4 
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4’ 
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci’ 
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

But since this isn´t working I guess that I have to decode the variable `adress` somehow?

So how can I decode a JSON string in asp classic?
Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Would this help...

```
'remove BOM if present
If (Len(Trim(adress)) > 0) Then
Dim AscValue : AscValue = Asc(Trim(adress))
If ((AscValue = -15441) Or (AscValue = 239)) Then : fileContent = Mid(Trim(adress),4) : End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but it turned out to be the ODBC driver that was wrong.